# Can we Install a plugin or software from browser?

Tags: browser, installation, automation

We are developing a website which is required some software to install for first time like flash player for youtube...

but the question is without asking the user can we install it?

i found this some where but [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) ., but i dont want to ask the permission from user/OS. By calling the website only software should install if it is not installed on the perticular machine....

Is it possible?

This is not a good question, i know but we want to develop an inhouse website, the website will not go to live for remote users. if any security settings we need to change in our systems we are ready to do.......

Comment: No downvote. Installing anything on users' machine without their consent is a bad idea.

Comment: There are ways of doing this, but it is illegal in most countries as it is no different to a malware/hack attack. Certainly no responsible person will post how this is done on a public forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not possible. Browsers are meant to run in sandboxes to prevent remote execution of arbitrary code. So you will need to ask the user for permissions.

If you are on java world you can use JavaWebStart. Otherwise, you could run a FLASH SCRIPT to provide the extra functionality you need for your WebSite. But since you didn't provide extra information on your issue, it's difficult to give you proper recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean installing it as in launching the install without the user having to click a "INSTALL" button or do you mean install the software without the user noticing you've done anything at all.

The second is not possible for security reasons.